# I can't copy to clipboard something starting with "javascript:"

Tags: javascript

```
function copyURI(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let a = ' ';
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(a+evt.target.getAttribute('href')).then(() => {
      /* clipboard successfully set */
    }, () => {
      /* clipboard write failed */
    });
}
```

if I change **a** to anything other than spaces, I'll be able to copy the link in the format:
javascript:x
but if there's a space or no character in fron the the link, it won't be copied

Can someone help me?
Is there a character that gets ignored by the url bar but not by js?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. You should supply some examples where in some cases it does work and then contrast it with what you require or expect. Right now, in order to help you, I would need to recreate the whole environment and still not sure if it would match your needs. And, a correct grammar does help to understand your post.

Comment: If I copy and paste that code into a file and trigger it via a click handler on a link with `javascript:console.log('hi')` as its `href` and change `a` to be just `""` (a blank string), clicking the link copies the text `javascript:console.log('hi')` to the clipboard. I've tried a Chromium browser and Firefox. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, providing **alll** the necessary code and markup and proper instructions for reproducing the problem.